# Dotnet Blazor deploy on Digital Ocean Error: Unable to retrieve the specified information about the process or thread

Tags: asp.net, docker, asp.net-core, blazor, digital-ocean

I built a Blazor application that is deployed on DigitalOcean. Everything was working for 3-4 weeks then suddenly, i'm getting this error in the CICD build pipeline. I'm building my app using a container. Heres a link to my repo : [GitHub](https://github.com/MaxThom/game-boulette-v2)

```
INFO[0026] Running: [/bin/sh -c dotnet restore "GameBoulette.Server/GameBoulette.Server.csproj"] 
[2021-09-18 23:42:37] Unhandled exception. System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (29): Unable to retrieve the specified information about the process or thread.  It may have exited or may be privileged.
[2021-09-18 23:42:37]    at System.Diagnostics.Process.GetStat()
[2021-09-18 23:42:37]    at System.Diagnostics.Process.get_StartTimeCore()
[2021-09-18 23:42:37]    at System.Diagnostics.Process.get_StartTime()
[2021-09-18 23:42:37]    at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Program.Main(String[] args)
[2021-09-18 23:42:37] Aborted
[2021-09-18 23:42:37] error building image: error building stage: failed to execute command: waiting for process to exit: exit status 134
[2021-09-18 23:42:37] 
[2021-09-18 23:42:37] command exited with code 1
```

Here is my digital ocean app config:

```yaml
name: game-boulette
region: sfo
services:
- dockerfile_path: /GameBoulette/GameBoulette.Server/Dockerfile
  github:
    branch: main
    deploy_on_push: true
    repo: MaxThom/game-boulette-v2
  http_port: 8080
  instance_count: 1
  instance_size_slug: professional-xs
  name: game-boulette
  routes:
  - path: /
  health_check:
    http_path: /api/health
  source_dir: /GameBoulette/
```

I can build and run the image on my machine, any idea?
Thanks!

Comment: Have you been able to find the solution? Facing the same issue, DO support was unable to provide any assistance unfortunately.

Comment: Sadly no, ive decided to use github action to build my image instead. And it works. Ive replaced my apps with a k8s cluster.